# How on earth did you discover it, and what in the world did you discover?”

Tags: meaning

In "The Dagger with Wings" by G. K. Chesterton, Dr. Boyne was talking to Father Brown after the priest said the murderer was trying to convince him to believe fake superstitions about the murder although he could have simply killed him and escaped.

“I wonder why he didn’t,” observed Boyne. “I don’t understand it; but I don’t understand anything yet. How on earth did you discover **it**, and **what** in the world did you discover?”

I can't understand how Boyne asked him about the way that he discovered "it" with, which implies that he know the thing that this "it" refer to, then asked him about this thing by what, as if he don't know it?!!

Does it mean what else?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rephrased, - "How were you able to find it, and what did you actually find?"  Basically, Boyne is admitting he doesn't know how it was found, and furthermore, he really doesn't even understand what was found.  His is completely in the dark and needs a lot explaining to understand.  The first 2 sentences back this up.

You are correct that the first part would imply that he knows what "it" is, but then he clarifies that he can't even state that correctly with the second part.

Comment: Thank you so much